# Re-sync deleted files from rsync

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I need to recover files that have been deleted.

My scenario:

I have a rsync script that runs at 9PM and mirrors everything from server1 directory to another directory on backup server2.

A couple of files have been accidentally deleted from server1.

How do I recover those files from server1 with rsync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do so with the `--update` option. According to the man page

> This forces rsync to skip any files
>   which exist on the destination and
>   have a modified time that is newer
>   than the source file. (If an existing
>   destination file has a modification
>   time equal to the source file's, it
>   will be updated if the sizes are
>   different.)

Answer (score 1):

From server1:

```
scp root@server2:/backupdir/myfile /mydirectory/myfile
```

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for.  I'm trying to recover only the deleted files, not the entire directory.

Comment: Ah okay. I assumed you had a list of specific files that were deleted.